# MS Word - How to make different caption style for the table captions in Appendix and main body?

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents, caption

I am trying to create a document where I have different headings and captions for the main body and the appendices. I have created the headings, where I have Chapter 1 and Appendix A (I did this through creating a header 7 for the appendix titles, and changing the number style).

For my tables, I want Table 1, Table 2, ... Table A.1, Table A.2, Table B.1 etc

When I create a caption for the appendix, I enter caption, click on format, and tick the box "including chapter headings". However that changes all my captions in the document. So I either get

Table 0.1, Table 0.2, ..., Table A.1, Table A.2

Or Table 1, Table 2, ...., Table 8, Table 9

How do I create different captions for the main body and the appendices?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer. When I insert a caption for my tables in the Appendix, I need to give them a New Label. I create the label "Appendix Table", and I check the box to ensure that these include the chapter heading, and also make sure I including the heading style to define the chapter number (in my case, I created a Heading 7, which has the number format A, B, C). When I create the caption, I simply delete the word "Appendix". I now have Table A-1, A-2, etc

Then, when I insert the table of contents, I can add the table of contents for Appendix Table directly below the TOC for Tables.

Comment: I found a better way. Your way works for me on Word for Mac 16.4 except the last part where you insert the TOC for the Appendix Table (by which I am guessing you mean Table of Figures?). In my case, I have a Table of Contents, a Table of Figures, and a Table of Figures for the tables. Using your method, when I inset the Table of Figures for the Appendix Table it replaces the Table of Figures for the regular tables. Instead, define a new style "Table Caption", insert Table of Figures, click "Options", check "Style" under "Build table of figures from:" and select the new style "Table Caption".